# generating pdf thumbnails in Google Sites

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

Is there a script that can generate a PDF thumbnail in Google sites. Right now I'm using DocList to fetch the name and size of some PDF files in my Google drive and list them on Google Sites. I would like a script that can generate the pdf thumbail of those files as well.

Answer (score 1):

No, You can not get the file icons programatically. You need to use icon images to display it in UI using UIService or HtmlService. You may check a example by Saqib Ali [here](https://sites.google.com/site/collaboratory20/journal/displayingthecontentsofagoogledocscollectionusingthetreeuiwidgetingoogleappsscript). He is uisng UiService and DocList to display the Items in a collection.